# What's the best practice for fixed point math in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin

I'm reviewing some of the deployed smart contracts with fixed-point math operations, and I'm seeking to improve the code by importing a library or deployed contract standard that does fixed-point math functions.

Something like Openzeppelin but for fixed-point math functions.

Which is the best practice for fixed-point math using an imported library? and which is the best library for this?